# Fetching JSON data from multiple web api methods ($q.all)

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angular-promise, angularjs-http

I have a simple app with a form. When the form loads I want to call a couple of web api methods to fetch the json data used to initialize the form. The form is working fine with hardcoded data in my factory class. I am unsure how I can make multiple request in that file and is kind of stuck.

The form:

```
<div class="modal-header" style="text-align:center">
<h3 class="modal-title">Configure</h3>
<div style="margin-top:10px">
    <button tabindex="100" class="btn btn-success pull-left" type="submit">Submit</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning pull-right" ng-click="close($event)">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="col-sm-6" style="width: 100%;">
    <form name="joinForm">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Symbol</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <select ng-model="simulationsettings.symbols" ng-  options="key as value for (key,value) in symbols"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Interval</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <select ng-model="simulationsettings.intervals" ng-options="key as value for (key,value) in intervals"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The controller:

```
mainApp2.controller("moduleConfigformController",
function moduleConfigformController($scope, moduleConfigformService,$uibModalInstance) {
$scope.close = function(e) {
  $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
  e.stopPropagation();
};
$scope.simulationsettings = moduleConfigformService.simulationsettings;
$scope.symbols = $scope.simulationsettings.symbols;
$scope.intervals = $scope.simulationsettings.intervals;
});
```

The factory class that holds the (hard coded) data for the form:

```
mainApp2.factory("moduleConfigformService",
function () {
    return {
        simulationsettings: {
            symbols: {
                'symbol1': "symbol1",
                'symbol2': "symbol2"
            },
            intervals: {
                '60': "1 minute",
                '120': "2 minutes",
                '180': "3 minutes"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Instead of hard coded values I want to call the server but is pretty stuck after several hours of research and trail and error:

```
mainApp2.factory("moduleConfigformService",
function () {

    function getSymbols() {
        return $http.get("/api/getsymbols");
    }

    function getIntervals() {
        return $http.get("/api/getIntervals");
    }
    return {
        simulationsettings: {
            symbols : getSymbols()
            },
            intervals : getIntervals()
    }
});
```

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: The `$http` Service doesn't return values. It returns *promises*. See [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - General Usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage). Also using promise based APIs from a factory can be a bit tricky. I would suggest writing and debugging the code in the controller and later re-factor to use a factory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $http Service doesn't return values. It returns *promises*. See [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - General Usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#general-usage). Also using promise based APIs from a factory can be a bit tricky. I would suggest writing and debugging the code in the controller and later re-factor to use a factory.

```
app.factory("moduleConfigformService",
function ($q,$http) {

    function getSymbols() {
        return $http.get("/api/getsymbols")
          .then(function (response) { 
            return response.data;
        });
    }

    function getIntervals() {
        return $http.get("/api/getIntervals")
          .then(function (response) {
            return response.data
        });
    }

    return {
        getSymbols: getSymbols,
        getIntervals: getIntervals,
        simulationsettings: function () {
            var promiseHash = {};
            promiseHash.symbols = getSymbols();
            promiseHash.intervals = getIntervals();
            return $q.all(promiseHash);
        }
    }
});
```

#### Usage

```
var settingsPromise = moduleConfigformService.simulationsettings();

settingsPromise.then(function(settings) {
   $scope.simulationsettings = settings;
}).catch(function(error) {
   throw error;
});
```

Comment: Now I just have to work out why my dropdownlist contains [object object], but that is a new problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

If i take a look at your controller, i don't see that you wait for the http request to return an answer.

You should take a look at [angularjs promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)
In short you have to have to use something like

```
moduleConfigformService.simulationsettings.then(function (response) {
//doSomeThingWithResponse
})
```

Comment: Thx. I will take a look at it.